# UITableView is "loaded" delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there a sort of delegate or implementation on when the UITableView is fully loaded and displayed on the screen?

Answer (score 3):

The data source delegate provides data to the table view for the life of the table. It works "on demand" so when the user scrolls up or down, the delegate is still there providing data. At what point would is say it's finished? When it's loaded "a screen" of data? What it's loaded *all* the cells?

So the short answer is "no," there is no such notification.

Comment: When the cycle of loading the visible cells are done in the first instance without any interaction